# Setting password in Ubuntu snappy with ARTIK10 board

Tags: ssh, password, ubuntu-core

I'm trying to use Ubuntu snappy with ARTIK 10 board. 
I registered SSH key on Ubuntu site but I stuck in this progress:

[image]

As you can see they want me to set password. But when I type password and press Enter, nothing happens. I did something wrong?

> $ ssh-keygen -t rsa

I made ssh key with this. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an account on the Ubuntu site, you should have added an SSH key public. That ssh key is now on your ARTIK 10. You should be able to login using ssh if your ip addresses are valid, and you have the corressponding ssh private key on the machine you are trying to ssh from